# Computed columns not showing links to documents in Dynamic View Panel

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using Dynamic View Panel (`xe:dynamicViewPanel`) to display views. In my XPage I pass the name of view as a parameter to URL and then I fetch it and put it into `viewName` property of data source. On my server I have Domino 8.5.3 with Upgrade Pack 1. On my local machine I have extension library from OpenNTF (`ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-853.20120320-1003`) installed.

According to my observation the Dynamic View Panel is showing the first non-categorized column as link to the document. So if in my first column of view I only write field name, say `UserName`, then that column is shown as link. But if I put in formula in first column as `@Name([CN]; UserName)` it doesn't show as a link, instead the next **non-computed** non-categorized column is shown as link. This behavior happens only with my server which has Domino 8.5.3 with Upgrade Pack 1.

But when I took a local copy of the database and tried to run on my localhost (which has extension library from OpenNTF) the computed column of `@Name([CN]; UserName)` shows as link.

Has anyone encountered this behavior? Is this a bug? Any work around?

Comment: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/defect.xsp?documentId=EF813AA0DF31DB2186257ABF0054A4E7&action=openDocument
but I believe it was discussed on openntf.org and fixed in extlib after UP1 release. so your only option is to use Extlib or wait for R9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: I have reported this bug on openntf and it was fixed.
http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/66d9103768cc2fed85256c59006b5433/c3ccbddbdc0e44bf8625796d00305196!OpenDocument

But it wasn't fixed in UP1 codestream.

I suggest to use ExtLib distribution, as it is more feature rich (and bug free) than Upgrade Pack. Thanks to new feature of 8.5.3 you can distribute latest ExtLib via update site so no installation on server is needed.

Comment: So I guess Extension Library would preferred instead of Upgrade Pack.

Comment: Yes. I was in doubt about which one to use, and ExtLib won: http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/66d9103768cc2fed85256c59006b5433/ed7fc0cc5374b80c8625796c002a7728!OpenDocument